# How to solve command conflict

Tags: r

There same commands in R packages.

I already use `%>%` in my R markdown script. And today I newly install dplyr package in rstudio.
 Then I notice there are 3 `%>%` in my rstudio, maybe will cause strange problem.

```
dplyr::%>%          # Objects exported from other packages
magrittr::%>%       # magrittr forward-pipe operator
stringr::%>%        # Pipe operator
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Have you had any problems with that? I don't think you need to do anything about it since they all do the same afaik.

Comment: Don't think it'll be a problem. If you check the documentation for all of them, they all act the same way. Specifically, `dplyr::%<%` explicitly says it imports from `magrittr::%<%`. Looking at the source code all of them are exactly the same.

Comment: That's really a problem. you can find may other example like `outlier`. you should notice from `outlier` package and `psych` package. that's different function.

Comment: Can you specifically say where those packages have their own version of `%>%`? I can't seem to find it

Comment: More formal comparison is: `identical(dplyr::"%>%",magrittr::"%>%");
identical(dplyr::"%>%",stringr::"%>%")`. Shows that all of these are identical to each other

Comment: Because you seem to wander in the `tidyverse`, you may also read [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/15/tidyverse-1-0-0/) about conflicts with other packages, and check the [`tidyverse_conflicts` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyverse/versions/1.0.0/topics/tidyverse_conflicts). Quite a few have been bitten by this...